# C++ creating a graph out of dot coordinates and finding MST

Tags: c++, graph, coordinates

I'm trying to make a program in which the user inputs n dot coordinates, 0 < n <= 100. Supposedly, the dots have to be connected, lets say, with ink in a way that you can get e.g from point A to point X while following the inked line and using the least amount of ink possible.

I thought of using Prim Algorithm or something like that to get the MST but for that I need a graph. In all the webpages I've looked they don't really explain that, they always already have the graph with its edges already in there.

I need help specifically creating a graph in C++ out of a bunch of (x, y) coordinates, like the user inputs:

- 0 0
- 4 4
- 4 0
- 0 4

Please note I'm just starting with C++ and that I can't use any weird libraries since this would be for a page like CodeForces where you only get to use the native libraries.

(For the ones that are also doing this and are here for help, the correct output for this input would be 12)

Comment: Why can't you assume a complete graph?

Comment: It is not clear what your exact problem is. If you have an assignment, can you quote it verbatim?

Comment: "Description
In an episode of the Dyke show, Richie connects the freckles on his Dad's back to form a picture of the Liberty Bell. Alas,one of the freckles turns out to be a scar, so his Ripley's engagement falls through. Consider Dick's back to be a plane with freckles at various (x,y)locations. Your job is to tell Richie how to connect the dots so as to minimise the amount of ink used. Richie connects the dots by drawing straight lines between pairs, possibly lifting the pen between lines. When Richie is done there must be a sequence of connected lines from any freckle to any other freckle."

Comment: I'm just not sure if I should just connect everything with everything because with Prim, every dot that is already in your tree would have to check every connection they have to look for the smallest distance and if I have 100 dots I just thought it would be too many comparisons and that it would just take too long.

Comment: You should connect everything with everything, get your solution right, and think about performance later.

Answer (score 0):

To assume a complete graph may be most appropriate as suggested by "Beta".

Following code may creates edges between every pair of two dots from a list of dots in the array dots and returns the number of edges created.
After execute this code, you may be able to apply Prim Algorithm for finding MST.

```
// Definition of Structure "node" and an array to store inputs
typedef struct node {
        int x; // x-cordinate of dot
        int y; // y-cordinate of dot
} dots[100]; 

// Definition of Structure "edge"
typedef struct edge {
         int t1; // index of dot in dots[] for an end.
         int t2; // index of dot in dots[] for another end.
         float weight; // weight (geometric distance between two ends) 
} lines[];

// Function to create edges of complete graph from an array of nodes.
//   Argument: number of nodes stored in the array dots.
//   ReturnValue: number of edges created.
//   Assumption: the array lines is large enough to store all edges of complete graph

int createCompleteGraph(int numberOfNodes){
  int i,j,k,x-diff,y-diff;
  k=0; // k is index of array lines
  for (i=0; i<numberOfNodes-1; i++) {// index of a node at one end
    for (j=i+1; j<numberOfNodes; j++) {// index of a node at another end
      lines[k].t1 = i;
      lines[k].t2 = j;
      x-diff = dots[i].x - dots[j].x;
      y-diff = dots[i].y - dots[j].y;
      lines[k].weight = sqrt(x-diff * x-diff + y-diff * y-diff) // calculate geometric distance
      k++; 
    }
  }
  return k;
}
```

Comment: I read about Prim's algorithm and in all of the examples I found, it had a weighted graph. I did think of just imagining the dots in a graph and in my node struct, just adding  something like a "weight" int array with the distance from that node to the others; but then, if I had N nodes, I would've also had N arrays size N-1 and with Prim I would've had to check a bunch of distances and didn't know if it was a correct way of doing it. Here I would have a lines array size the number of connections between dots. Which do you think would be faster? This, mine or another idea you may have?

Comment: My code generates edges with weight. Prime's algorithm may give the answer in O(N*N) time. I think your PC gives you the answer in reasonable time for N<=100.